# Single layer Autoencoder for CIFAR10 database using Keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, autoencoder, image-compression

I am using following Autoencoder (https://stackabuse.com/autoencoders-for-image-reconstruction-in-python-and-keras/) to train Autoencoder with 50 neurons in single layer with 50 first images of CIFAR 10.

However, my I am not getting good results. The reconstructed images are really bad.

Following is the code in python:
https://github.com/Sinaconstantine/AE-based-image-compression-/blob/master/prob4.ipynb

Can you please comment my problem in the code?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried visualizing the model's output on the training data? I would not expect a network trained on only 50 images to be able to generalize to the test dataset, so visualizing the performance of the network on the training data can help make sure everything is working. For this amount of input data, the model seems to be doing pretty well at reconstructing images it has never seen before. If you want it to perform better on the test images, maybe try training on a lot more input data, and I would also suggest adding some more neurons in that case.

Comment: When increasing number of neurons or having same number of neurons but increasing the number of input data the performance increasing significantly (which is expected...).
So based on your comment, I believe AE is doing really good for images that have not seen before and there is not a way to increase the performance anymore. Right?

Comment: Yes, probably not